# MYSQL Connector/C++ Binary tree - CART. How i can choose only part of rows

Tags: c++, mysql

I want to create a "20 questions game" and if the player thinks about word which I don't have in DB game will add it witch player's answers.
Generally how DB would look or what query I need to do next step.

My database for now looks like this:
`I have 3 tables:
- questions
   - id
   - question // questions witch my game will ask a player.
- words
   - id
   - word // words just words
- relations
   - id_question
   - id_word
   - value // One of three values (-1,0,1)`
 "-1" mean I dont have data about this combination question and word, 
"0" mean answer is "No", 
"1" mean answer is "Yes".

And my algorithm:

1. I'm asking DB for questions with the most count of answers (1 and 0).
   "SELECT `id_question`, COUNT(id_question) AS `answers` FROM relations GROUP BY id_question ORDER BY `answers` DESC"
2. I'm asking DB for a count of "1" for questions from &1.
   "SELECT `id_question`, COUNT(id_question) AS `positive` FROM relations WHERE `value` = 1 GROUP BY id_question ORDER BY `answers` DESC"
3. Finding questions where I have most answers (&1) and the ratio "Yes" to "No" is closest to 0.5
4. Asking the player he can choose one of 3 answers "Yes", "No", "I don't know".
5. (Here I have trouble) According to the answer, I want to change my queries, but I don't have an idea of how to ask DB to search only in that part of words where for example answer for question number 2 is "No" (0).
6. If I have only 1 word or I asked 20 times program will end but if no back to &1.

So, I think my DB need one more table or a few columns. 
If the answer is I need a table I don't have an idea how it would look. 
I thought about add column to "words" table with string for example "0110110-1" and position of the number will be the id of the question but this would be hard to write.

My second thinks were to add one column for every question in word table but in the situation where I add a question I need to add next column and that doesn't look like the best choice.

Or maybe is in MySQL is a possibility to choose only part of rows.

I hope it is clearly written because I'm not good at English.

Comment: `I want to create a "20 questions game" and if the player thinks about word which I don't have in DB game will add it witch player's answers.` Do you mean if the player inputs something which is not in you DB, you store that input in a DB?

Comment: Yes, for example, if a player thought about a cat and I didn't have that word in DB, so after the game, I will ask about what word player thought and add this to DB so every game my game is better, something like Akinator.

Comment: Just store the words that the user entered and are not there in your database in a vector of strings. And input all of them in the database one by one using something like a range based for loop

Comment: Yea I know, but I don't have trouble with it. I need help with the query in &5 when I get the answer from the player and need to find the next question, for example, I had the question "Is that an animal?" answer "yes". So now I want to find the best question only for animals. So I need to modify my query, but I just add "SELECT `id_word` [...] WHERE id_question = 2 AND value = 1 [...]" that give me id words, but I don't know how to search only in that words.

Comment: If you have a predefined set of questions store the types in an enum class. Add another parameter in your table something like type. If the user says yes on animal, search the database for questions of type animal (or whatever the user wants)